# Socket data transfer - out of memory exception

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-8, out-of-memory

I'm sending files of about 10 Mbs each one from pc to phone using TCP sockets.
In the phone-side I'm receiving data like this:

```
  Dim B As Byte() = New Byte(Socket.ReceiveBufferSize - 1) {}
  Me.Args.SetBuffer(B, 0, Socket.ReceiveBufferSize)
  Me.Socket.ReceiveAsync(Me.Args)
```

ReceiveBufferSize property is set to 30000000.
And this is the way I read it:

```
 Dim R As Byte() = New Byte(Me.Args.BytesTransferred - 1) {}
 Dim s As New MemoryStream(Me.Args.Buffer)
 Me.Args.SetBuffer(0, 0)

 s.Read(R, 0, ntpData.Length)
 s.Dispose()
```

This process takes a huge amounth of memory (about 300Mbs) so I can't run the app in low-price devices that hves a memory usage limit of 180Mbs.
I can't `.Dispose()` the socket every time the phone receives something since it would throw an OjbectDisposed exception.
How can I free up memory?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the question could possibly be turned around. How can you *use* less memory? For instance you could:

- download the data in smaller chunks from the socket and reuse the same buffer rather than reallocating it.
- write the data to an Isolated Storage stream rather than memory, and only load into memroy what you need to show in the app at a given point in time.

(this would be dependent on the exact scenario you are working in)

You should also make sure that the memory you have already allocated is garbage collected once you are done with it by making sure that nothing is holding a reference to it

Also, have you profiled the app to confirm that it really is this socket memory that is causing the problem or is it actually due to some other memory elsewhere?

Comment: I "commented" others procedures in the application and yes, I am pretty sure that is the problem. However I'll try the first solution and, if  it's not enough, I'll go also for the second one. Thanks

Comment: Displaying large numbers of images in the UI is a common cause of high memory usage, so watch out for that.

Comment: Sure, but I'm not displaying any image. The problem is the ReceiveBufferSize, which is too large, but can't figure out how to perform ReceiveAsync in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

You are so lucky because you got out of memory during your development stage.

Never, Ever use buffer (byte array) size greater than 84KB on windows Phone, the GC does not collect data in byte array greater than 84KB.

your code should be similar to:

```
Try
            stream.Position = 0
            Dim totalRead As Long = 0
            Dim readBuffer As Integer
            Dim bufferSize As Long = 4096 'under 86KB
            Dim readArray = New Byte(bufferSize - 1) {}
            While totalRead < stream.Length
                readBuffer = Await stream.ReadAsync(readArray, 0, bufferSize)
                totalRead += readBuffer
                'Use readArray here
            End While
            stream.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Log My exception
        Finally
            stream.Dispose()
        End Try
```

just try to change your code similar to this and you will not exceed 50MB RAM

Good Luck.

Comment: This is not helpful in my case, infact I don't know the length of the stream before processing it. All I can do is to set a buffer in which the stream will be put as I shown in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't find any real solution to my problem, I managed to do it using a workaround.

Every packet of data is marked with an header.
Before sending heavy amounth of data, I send to the client a packet with a different header. Then the client recognize that kind of header and read the bytes next to the header: they contains the leangth of the stream which is next to come. So the client set the buffer length and wait for the data to come.